# What does Leela have on her right forearm?

Tags: futurama

I checked [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leela_%28Futurama%29), [Futurama Wiki](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Turanga_Leela), and [The Infosphere](http://theinfosphere.org/Leela): None of them mentions what the device she has on her right forearm is.

[image: Leela and a freehand circle]

What is that?

Comment: The drop shadow on the red circle really impressed me, for some reason. Good work! :)

Comment: Sci-fi writers often incorporate a generic gadget into their plotlines which can be used to fulfill any need a character may encounter. If you listen to the futurama commentaries, the writers discuss how Bender's chest is used for this purpose. On Doctor Who, the sonic screwdriver serves this purpose. Leela's wrist band has the same use, and its purpose varies depending on what the plot requires / what is funny.

Comment: Since it rebels along with the rest of the electrical devices on Earth, apparently it counts as a robot.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a multi-function device that Leela specifically referred to as her [Wristlojackimator](http://theinfosphere.org/Leela%27s_Wrist_Thingy) in the episode ["How Hermes Requisitioned His Groove Back"](http://theinfosphere.org/How_Hermes_Requisitioned_His_Groove_Back). All other mentions she makes of it are general and vague (i.e. "this thing I wear on my wrist" or "my wrist thingy").

The [functions/abilities](http://theinfosphere.org/Leela%27s_Wrist_Thingy#Appearances) of her "wrist thingy" are:

- A communication device.
- Some degree of AI, since it abandoned her during the [robot uprising](http://theinfosphere.org/The_3001_Robot_Uprising) in the episode ["Mother's Day"](http://theinfosphere.org/Mother%27s_Day).
- A tracking beacon (like a [LoJack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LoJack), hence the name) which she used to track a pneumatic tube container in the episode ["How Hermes Requisitioned His Groove Back"](http://theinfosphere.org/How_Hermes_Requisitioned_His_Groove_Back).
- General [tricorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricorder)-like behavior, such as when she determined that [Popplers](http://theinfosphere.org/Popplers) were safe to eat in the episode ["The Problem with Popplers"](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Problem_with_Popplers).
- A laser, used medically to put Fry's nose back on (["Spanish Fry"](http://theinfosphere.org/Spanish_Fry)) and as a weapon ([*Into the Wild Green Yonder*](http://theinfosphere.org/Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder)).
- Playing video games, which she did in the episode ["The Luck of the Fryrish"](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Luck_of_the_Fryrish) and in [*The Beast with a Billion Backs*](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Beast_with_a_Billion_Backs).
- A tissue dispenser, as shown in [*Bender's Big Score*](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender%27s_Big_Score).

In addition, as NominSim mentions in a comment, Leela keeps the bracelet she was found with as a child underneath it (["Leela's Homeworld"](http://theinfosphere.org/Leela%27s_Homeworld)).

Comment: She keeps the bracelet that her parents gave her when they left her at the orphanage underneath it too.